# Jquery alert box after Session expired

Tags: php, javascript

I have the code

```
if(isIdleTimeExceeded())
{
    logout();
    header("Location:".$baseurl."index.php");
    exit();
}
```

In IdleTimeExceeded I am checking the time.

I want to get jQuery alert box after session expires.

Comment: no need for jquery just a simple javascript alert..   alert("yourtext");

Comment: Do you want the alert to display only when the page is refreshed/a new page is loaded, or on the current page when the session times out?

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is PHP code. But after the page has been sent to the client, you no longer have access to php functions. If idle time means the user hasn't switch page in x amount of seconds, then you just need javascript.

```
<script>
//the function IdleToLong will be called after 30seconds. 
//This means if the page reloads, it starts over.
setTimeout(IdleToLong, 30 * 1000); // 30 seconds

function IdleToLong() {
  alert('Move your ass');

  //If you also need to logout in PHP then you must notify the server that a user has been idle to long.
  $.get('logout.php?reason=idle').complete(function() { 
     window.location.href = '/';
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create Alert using javascript
`echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Logged out!!");</script>';`